# How to change / apply change clothes in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I am unable to change my clothes in PUBG. I can change it temporary, but don't see any `apply` button or something like it.

How to accomplish?

[image]

Comment: I remember this screen being weird... maybe try double clicking the item you want to equip? Or maybe F or E? (Whatever the "use" key is in this game)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the item you want to use and the select EQUIP. It took me a while to figure it out.